# Sending a command in my robot world game to a server to be executed and have a response sent(via json strings)

Tags: java, json, serversocket

I have been working on a robot game where you name a robot and give it certain valid commands that it can respond to. (Forward n[n is the number of steps], Back n, Left, Right). The robot operates in a Cartesian plane and will move along the x and y-axis after starting at zero. My team and I are now moving towards taking this game and making it a java multisocket version where there can be multiple robots in one world.

I am trying to change it to a way that then sends that command that the player put in as a message to the server and then get a response back from a server. I am a beginner and don't know where to start.

Here's an example of a command class.

`public class ForwardCommand extends Command {
@Override
public boolean execute(Robot target) {
int nrSteps = Integer.parseInt(getArgument());
if (target.updatePosition(nrSteps)){
target.setStatus("Moved forward by "+nrSteps+" steps.");
} else {
target.setStatus("Sorry, I cannot go outside my safe zone.");
}
return true;
}

```
public ForwardCommand(String argument) {
    super("forward", argument);
}
```

}`

I tried to change my main Play.java file into a client.java version and now I am at the point that we need to take the commands and turn them into something that the server entails. What is the next step and what do I need to look into because its my first time dealing with java socket programming.